# Animate Vertex Groups in Geometry Nodes

Tags: animation, geometry-nodes, vertex-groups

I am trying to animate a digital clock in Blender. My first approach was to do it with a hair particle system until I found out you cannot animate the density, plus changing the number of instances is a bit too much work for something as simple as that. My second try was to create a geometry nodes setup. It looks the following:

[image: Node Setup with wished outcome]

The Vertex Group Input on the upper right properties panel controls the vertex group used as defined in the lower right properties panel.

As this is a clock, the time changes. But I cannot figure out how to animate the vertex group input as it is an attribute.

Can you give me a hint on where to look for a solution or how to solve this problem?

Thank you.

My reference are the digital Rolex clocks you see on the tennis courts.
Like this: https://hauteliving.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/shutterstock_94239481-752x501.jpg

OUTCOME:
First of all thanks for the help Chris. After looking at the answer I decided to create a font with the numbers and use it with the raycast node. The screenshot below shows the final solution where I can change the display number via a custom property.

[image: Final Version]

Comment: do you just want to change the numbers or do some other (or more) animation?

Comment: I would like to only change the numbers.

Comment: i updated my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

unfortunately i am not sure what you want to have, but you can have this:

[image]

with this node setup:

[image]

or this:

[image]

with this node setup:

[image]

UPDATE:

for "just counting" you can use this:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Will have a go and try to make. Thank you.

Comment: you are welcome

Comment: Went back to drawing board and found a solution. Thanks for the input. I updated my original question with the solution.